# Site columns default value for subsites

Tags: sharepoint, metadata, content-type, site-column

I am trying to figure out how to implement the following scenario. I have multiple project sites with the same structure (the structure contains subsites and libraries). I want to tag each document with a projectnumber (eg 100-050-BCD). How can i set this as default for each subsite in the site collection, so the user does not have to fill in the number over and over again.

My first approach was to create a content-type "contract" on site collection level which contains the site columns (Title, Description, Projectnumber etc)  but i cannot set a value for each subsite. Right? So i think this could not work.

with the second approach i would use managed metadata. I would create a column on the subsite level called projectnumber with a default value from the managed metadata store. So in the metadata store I create the projectnumbers and set this as default in the subsite column type. This column is added in the libraries in the subsite. I then should be able to use the metadata as refinement in my searchresults, or not? The ugly part in it is that i have different column types "projectnumber" for each subsite, that feels not quite right.

The question is am i using the right approach or should i use another one and could this be done much easier?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using the tag for? Is it for searching?

I would probably make the site collection url contain the project code. eg

http://yoursite/projects/100-050-BCD

So that way, if someone searchs for 100-050-BCD, everything in the project site collection should be returned. They can add extra filters as they need to.

The url can also be used in the standard search refinements (on the left of the search results page), so if someone searchs for eg "work request", then they can filter by url (which would be filtering by project)

Comment: The tag indeed is for refinement in the search. So this idea is indeed a pretty good one.